# Converting a real number to imaginary

Tags: python, numpy

For the code below, to convert a number to imaginary:

```
def output_imag(a)
    return a * 1j
```

Is this the right way to do this? Because `a * 1j` is simple enough, but I wonder whether there is a more correct way to do this.

Edit 2014-02-06:

Thanks for all the answers! Actually the function I defined is a terrible way to say this... What I actually tried to do is this:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.r_[0:1:100j]
```

This code will generate an array like np.linspace(0, 1, 100).
Now I wanted to make the "100" a variable, like np.linspace(0, 1, number)
but np.r_[0:1:numberj] couldn't work, only np.r_[0:1:number*1j] works.

So, that's how I've been wondering: a better way than number*1j? It seems not...

Thank you for all who answered!

Comment: `output_imag(a)` is 8 characters longer than `a * 1j`, including spaces.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Thanks! So a * 1j seems to be the way to do it?

Comment: I'd skip the somewhat cryptic `r_` object and use `np.linspace(0, 1, number)` instead.  More characters, but much more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is `complex(0, a)`.

I would also argue that defining your own function just for this is counter-productive as it obscures the intent.